# multi-step form, not submitting on last stage

Tags: javascript

Update:

I have added new js code which fixed my issue and by adding it here, it may help others.

Multi-step form works (codepen), and I have integrated it into my server-side scripting.  Still working. The code is all available here. (https://codepen.io/ActiveCodex/pen/OVBeMg#code-area) The button element labelled 'Next' moves the user along through the steps.  On the last step, the JS changes the labelling of the button 'Next' to be a 'Submit' button but it doesn't submit to anywhere.  I want to add that 'Submit' functionality without breaking the 'Next' button functionality.  Either to submit via Ajax or the usual form 'post' method.

I wrapped the div id='form' into a <form> element and whilst that would submit, it did so even when the 'Next' button was clicked on and not only when the submit button was clicked. 
(I'm not experienced in .js since perl & php are my norm). I added an event listener but the data is not in js variables. I am asking for tip on what I should be looking for - eg a listener or a submit function or something I can google for.  I have tried to 'preventDefault()' but that has prevented everything on the form.

html code firstly...

````
  <div id='form' class='form' action="/cgi-bin/real-estate-dashboard-dev/processing_scripts/edit-listings-data.pl" method='get'> 
    <h1 class='property_summary'>Property Summary</h1>

    <input id="one" type="radio" name="stage" checked="checked" />
    <input id="two" type="radio" name="stage" />
    <input id="three" type="radio" name="stage" />
    <input id="four" type="radio" name="stage" />
    <input id="five" type="radio" name="stage" />
    <input id="six" type="radio" name="stage" />

    <div class="stages">
        <label for="one">1</label>
        <label for="two">2</label>
        <label for="three">3</label>
        <label for="four">4</label>
        <label for="five">5</label>
        <label for="six">6</label>
    </div>

    <span class="progress"><span></span></span>
    <div class='panels'>
      <div data-panel="one">
        <h4>Stage 1</h4>

        <p>Number of Receptions</p>
        <select name="number_of_reception_rooms" style='padding: 10px;font-size:1.5em;'> 
          <option value='' style='font-weight:700;'>Number of Receptions</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2" selected='selected'>2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>       
        </select> 
      </div>
      <div data-panel="two">
        <h4>Stage 2</h4>

        <p>Number of Ensuites</p>
        <select name="number_of_ensuites" style='padding: 10px;font-size:1.5em;'> 
          <option value='' style='font-weight:700;'>Number of Ensuites</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5" selected='selected'>5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>       
        </select> 
      </div> 


   <button>Next</button>

  </div>


<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-de7e2ef6bfefd24b79a3f68b414b87b8db5b08439cac3f1012092b2290c719cd.js"></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script id="rendered-js">
      $('.form .stages label').click(function () {
  var radioButtons = $('.form input:radio');
  var selectedIndex = radioButtons.index(radioButtons.filter(':checked'));
  selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1;
});

$('.form button').click(function () {
  var radioButtons = $('.form input:radio');
  var selectedIndex = radioButtons.index(radioButtons.filter(':checked'));

  selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 2;

  $('.form input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(' + selectedIndex + ')').prop('checked', true);

  if (selectedIndex == 6) {
    $('button').html('Submit');


  }
});

     // not working at all as I mentioned.
     document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("click", function(e) 
      {
      var bedrooms = e.number_of_bedrooms;

      e.preventDefault();
      console.log( 'number_of_bedrooms   ' + number_of_bedrooms);
     }) 

    //document.getElementById("myForm").submit();


    </script>  






```document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("click", function(e) 
      {
      //var number_of_bedrooms = e.target.number_of_bedrooms;

      e.preventDefault();
      //console.log( 'number_of_bedrooms   ' + number_of_bedrooms);
})

So the expected result is that the 'Next' button continues to step me through the form but on the last step, the submit button must submit the data in the div &lt;id='form'&gt; to a new script when I click it.

...code that fixed my issue...

$('#myForm button').click(function(e) {


      var radioButtons = $('#myForm input:radio');
      var selectedIndex = radioButtons.index(radioButtons.filter(':checked'));
      var numberForButtonAction = selectedIndex;
      numberForButtonAction = numberForButtonAction + 2;
      selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 2;

      $('.form input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(' + selectedIndex + ')').prop('checked', true);




      if (numberForButtonAction <= 5 ){  
          $('button').html('Next');
          document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("click", function(event){
          e.preventDefault();  
          });

      }

      if (numberForButtonAction == 6 ){  
          $('button').html('Submit');
          document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("click", function(event){
          e.preventDefault();  
          });

      }

      if (selectedIndex > 6) {
          $('button').html('Submit');    
      }

  });
````

Comment: What is `e.number_of_bedrooms`? Anything in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you.

First of all, I wrapped the entire form with the `form` tag, and set `onsubmit` function (alter it for your needs).

The second thing I did was to change the onclick listener on the next button. I changed it from `button` tag to `input` tag with `type="button"`. When the selected is equal to 6, I'm changing it to `type="submit"`. That way, when you click the submit, the form will submit!, and when you click next it will to its regular action.

Here is the code:

```js
$('.form .stages label').click(function() {
  var radioButtons = $('.form input:radio');
  var selectedIndex = radioButtons.index(radioButtons.filter(':checked'));
  selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1;
});

$('#last').click(function() {
  var radioButtons = $('.form input:radio');
  var selectedIndex = radioButtons.index(radioButtons.filter(':checked'));

  selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 2;

  $('.form input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(' + selectedIndex + ')').prop('checked', true);

  if (selectedIndex == 6) {
    document.getElementById('last').value = "Submit";
    document.getElementById('last').type = "submit";
    return false;
  }
});

function doSomething() {
  console.log('submitted');
}
```

```css
.stages {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}

.stages:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.stages label {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: solid 5px #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.stages label:after {
  content: '\2713';
  color: #0cc39f;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#one:checked~.stages label[for="one"],
#two:checked~.stages label[for="two"],
#three:checked~.stages label[for="three"],
#four:checked~.stages label[for="four"],
#five:checked~.stages label[for="five"],
#six:checked~.stages label[for="six"] {
  border-color: #0cc39f;
}

.stages label.active {
  border-color: purple !important;
}

#one:checked~.stages label,
#two:checked~.stages label[for="one"]~label,
#three:checked~.stages label[for="two"]~label,
#four:checked~.stages label[for="three"]~label,
#five:checked~.stages label[for="four"]~label,
#six:checked~.stages label[for="five"]~label {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#one:checked~.stages label:after,
#two:checked~.stages label[for="one"]~label:after,
#three:checked~.stages label[for="two"]~label:after,
#four:checked~.stages label[for="three"]~label:after,
#five:checked~.stages label[for="four"]~label:after,
#six:checked~.stages label[for="five"]~label:after {
  display: none;
}

.progress>span {
  background: #c0c0c0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-2.75em);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 0;
}

#two:checked~.progress span {
  width: calc(100% / 5 * 1);
}

#three:checked~.progress span {
  width: calc(100% / 5 * 2);
}

#four:checked~.progress span {
  width: calc(100% / 5 * 3);
}

#five:checked~.progress span {
  width: calc(100% / 5 * 4);
}

#six:checked~.progress span {
  width: calc(100% / 5 * 5);
}

.panels div {
  display: none;
}

#one:checked~.panels [data-panel="one"],
#two:checked~.panels [data-panel="two"],
#three:checked~.panels [data-panel="three"],
#four:checked~.panels [data-panel="four"],
#five:checked~.panels [data-panel="five"],
#six:checked~.panels [data-panel="six"] {
  display: block;
}


/* Custom code for the demo */

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #0cc39f;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

a {
  color: #0cc39f;
}

h2,
h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.form {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  margin: 4em;
  min-width: 480px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.panels div {
  border-top: solid 1px #c0c0c0;
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  padding: 1em 0 0;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em;
  width: 100%;
}

#last {
  background-color: #0cc39f;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: unset;
}

#last:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <h2>Multi Page Form (Pure CSS)</h2>
  <p>Divide long forms, enable users to flick back and forward.</p>
  <p>Use JS to validate form at the end of the stage and highlight tab(s) that contain(s) error.</p>
  <form onsubmit="doSomething(); return false;">
    <input id="one" type="radio" name="stage" checked="checked" />
    <input id="two" type="radio" name="stage" />
    <input id="three" type="radio" name="stage" />
    <input id="four" type="radio" name="stage" />
    <input id="five" type="radio" name="stage" />
    <input id="six" type="radio" name="stage" />

    <div class="stages">
      <label for="one">1</label>
      <label for="two">2</label>
      <label for="three">3</label>
      <label for="four">4</label>
      <label for="five">5</label>
      <label for="six">6</label>
    </div>

    <span class="progress"><span></span></span>

    <div class="panels">
      <div data-panel="one">
        <h4>Stage 1</h4>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
      </div>
      <div data-panel="two">
        <h4>Stage 2</h4>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
      </div>
      <div data-panel="three">
        <h4>Stage 3</h4>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Address" />
      </div>
      <div data-panel="four">
        <h4>Stage 4</h4>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
      </div>
      <div data-panel="five">
        <h4>Stage 5</h4>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" />
      </div>
      <div data-panel="six">
        <h4>Stage 6</h4>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Comment" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="last" value="Next">
    <br><br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Omri. It's been a while since I was on here - hence the delay in my response. Appreciative of your help, I shall examine your code and compare with the "solution" I hacked up myself. Thanks again.